# WITH position unexpected position using Mysql 8.0 Date Generation

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to use the [Date Generation Example](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive-date-series) to generate my own date range but I can't get the query to run.  The query fails and Workbench shows an error indicating my syntax is invalid.

**Am I overlooking/misunderstanding something about how this can be used?**  I can't use stored procedures so I hope this isn't limited to being used in that context.

```
use mydb;

WITH RECURSIVE dates (date) AS
(
  SELECT date + INTERVAL 1 DAY FROM dates
  WHERE DAYOFWEEK(date) = 1 AND
    date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR);
)
SELECT * FROM dates;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive CTE implemented in the MySQL 8+ requires the next syntax:

```
WITH RECURSIVE tbl (a,b,c) AS 
(
  SELECT ...  -- initial portion of rows
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ...  -- recursively added rows
)
SELECT * 
  FROM tbl
   ...
;
```

Refer to the documentation/primers for the proper recursive CTE using.

Comment: That works, but is it possible for me to add additional criteria to the "recursively added rows" - e.g. - `SELECT value, date FROM daily_stats WHERE date + INTERVAL 1 DAY <= NOW() AND daily_stats.name = 'user-count'`?  When I do that it says "unknown column name".

Comment: @Webnet Can you explain what exactly you want to get in general?

Comment: Nevermind, I had a simple mistake in my query. This answer is correct, thank you!